# Modifying element created with HTML5 template

Tags: javascript, html

I face a problem in javascript: I want to create an element based on a HTML5 template, and I want to modify it then.

Here is the minimal code reproducing the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <template id="tem">
            <a href="#">Test</a>
        </template>
        <script>
function instantiateTemplate(id) {
    var template = document.getElementById(id);
    var element = document.importNode(template.content, true);
    return template.parentNode.insertBefore(element, template);
}

var test = instantiateTemplate('tem');
test.textContent = 'Test2';
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fzn3w02o/

As you can see if you try it : the link keeps its initial content 'Test' whereas I expect it to be 'Test2'. How could you explain this?

PS: For this example, I could simply modify the template itself before importing it but in order to manage events, I need to modify it after its creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are targeting the `<template>` when you really need to target the `<a>`nchor.

```
var anchor = document.querySelector('a');
anchor.textContent = 'plop!'
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/ck5271ur/)

#### SNIPPET

```js
function instantiateTemplate(id) {
 var template = document.getElementById(id);
 var element = document.importNode(template.content, true);
 return template.parentNode.insertBefore(element, template);
}

var test = instantiateTemplate('tem');
var anchor = document.querySelector('a');
anchor.textContent = 'plop!'
```

```html
 <body>
  <template id="tem">
   <a href="#">Test</a>
  </template>
 </body>
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't understand it was the template I returned!
So returning `template.previousElementSibling` let us get the new element instead of the template.

Comment: I think it would be `test.previousElementSibling` because the var `template` is in a different scope.

Comment: Yes, I meant returning template.previousElementSibling in the function instantiateTemplate.